# What theory describe such images?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, soft-question, visualization, geometric-transformation

I make naive, [visual exploration of 2D images](https://github.com/adammaj1/2D-color-gradient-or-Procedural-texture), which can be described by simple functions, like:

1. $ y = f(x)$
2. $ y = f(x,y)$
3. $f(z) =
   \begin{cases}
    k(x,y) \\
    h(x,y)
   \end{cases}$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have read about algebraic and differential equations.

These images are used in :

- [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) and visualisation of complex functions
- [procedural texture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_texture)
- visualisation of [vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field)

Questions:

**Is there some math theory behind such images/functions/transformations ?**

**What is the difference between above functions?**

Comment: Look up "iterated function systems", for example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236021/is-it-possible-to-graph-complex-zeros-of-a-polynomial

Comment: @lhf Thx. But my question is what is the relation between clacc of functions and math theories/ problems ?